# How to enable/disable a TextCellEditor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am making an application which contains 2 views. The first one contains a tree viewer which displays the folders from my system and the second one contains a table viewer which displays the content of a directory selected in the first view. Long story short: a file explorer.

```java
    //initialization of the table viewer
    tableViewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);       
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(new FileTableContentProvider());
    tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new FileTableLabelProvider());     

    //from within the implementation of any view or editor
    /*
     * getSite() - Returns the site for this workbench part (a workbench part can be a view (IViewPart) or an editor (IEditorPart))
     * this view is a selection provider; the view sends the event to all the views registered to the selection service
     */
    getSite().setSelectionProvider(tableViewer);

    //the table column "Name" is added to the table viewer
    TableColumn columnName = new TableColumn(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.LEFT);
    columnName.setText("Name");
    columnName.setResizable(true);
    columnName.setWidth(200);

    //the table column "Date modified" is added to the table viewer
    TableColumn columnDateModified = new TableColumn(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.LEFT);
    columnDateModified.setText("Date modified");
    columnDateModified.setResizable(true);
    columnDateModified.setWidth(200);

    //the table column "Type" is added to the table viewer
    TableColumn columnType = new TableColumn(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.LEFT);
    columnType.setText("Type");
    columnType.setResizable(true);
    columnType.setWidth(200);       

    //make the header of the table visible
    tableViewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);      

    /*
     * getSite().getPage() - gets the active workbench page.
     */
    getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener("com.awebofcode.fileexplorer.view.filetree",(ISelectionListener)this);

    /*
     * add a doubleClickListener for:
     * 1) if the object selected is a file, then the file will be opened with the associated program
     * 2) if the object selected is a directory, then enter the folder and update the tree viewer
     */
    tableViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
            File itemSelected = (File) selection.getFirstElement();

            //if the selected item is a file a double click will launch the associated program
            if (itemSelected.isFile() && itemSelected.exists()){
                Program.launch(itemSelected.getAbsolutePath());
            }else if (itemSelected.isDirectory()){
                /*
                 * Update the tree viewer;
                 * PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(FileTreeView.ID) --> returns the view with the specified ID
                 * setSelection() will send an event and the setSelectionChanged will run
                 */
                ((FileTreeView) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(FileTreeView.ID)).getTreeViewer().setSelection(selection);
            }
        }

    });

    //create the cell editor
    CellEditor[] editors = new CellEditor[1];
    editors[0] = new TextCellEditor(tableViewer.getTable());
    tableViewer.setColumnProperties(new String[]{"Name", "Date modified", "Type"});
    //assign the cell editors to the table viewer
    tableViewer.setCellEditors(editors);
    //set the cell modifier to the table viewer
    tableViewer.setCellModifier(new NameCellModifier(tableViewer));
```

I created an action that will rename the selected file or folder from the second view.

When I click on the name of the file I don't want to enter in the editing mode.I want to stay in the selection mode and only after I click *File -> Rename* (action rename) the editing mode has to be enabled.

The problem is that I cannot find how to enable/disable the `TextCellEditor`.

Comment: Are there any ways to do this? I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a clean solution. I will explain you what I have done so far. I have modified the code that I have posted. I use `TableViewerColumn` instead of `TableColumn`.

Class FileTableView:

```java
public class FileTableView extends ViewPart implements ISelectionListener{

    private TableViewer tableViewer;
    private boolean cellEditable = false;
    private FirstColumnEditingSupport obj;

    public FileTableView() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        //initialization of the table viewer
        tableViewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI);  //SWT.MULTI - for multiple selection; SWT.FULL_SELECTION - for selection of an entire row   
        tableViewer.setContentProvider(new FileTableContentProvider());
        //it is not necessary to add a label provider for the table viewer because we will set a label provider for every column of the table
        //tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new FileTableLabelProvider());   

        //extract the table widget of the table viewer
        final Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
        //make the header of the table visible
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        //hide the lines of the table
        table.setLinesVisible(false);

        //create the columns of the table
        createColumns(parent, tableViewer);

        //set the sorter to the table viewer
        tableComparator = new TableViewerComparator();
        tableViewer.setComparator(tableComparator);

        //from within the implementation of any view or editor
        /*
         * getSite() - Returns the site for this workbench part (a workbench part can be a view (IViewPart) or an editor (IEditorPart))
         * this view is a selection provider; the view sends the event to all the views registered to the selection service
         */
        getSite().setSelectionProvider(tableViewer);        


        tableViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener(){
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event){
                setCellEditable(false);
            }
        }); 



    }

    /*
     * method used to update the viewer from outside
     */
    public void refresh(){
        tableViewer.refresh();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        tableViewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }



    //method that returns the table viewer
    public TableViewer getTableViewer(){
        return tableViewer;
    }


    /*
     * get the value of the cellEditable
     */
    public boolean getCellEditable(){
        return cellEditable;
    }

    /*
     * set the value of the cellEditable
     */
    public void setCellEditable(boolean cellEditable){
        this.cellEditable = cellEditable;
    }

    public FirstColumnEditingSupport getEditingSupport(){
        return obj;
    }

    /*
     * method that creates columns of the table
     */
    private void createColumns(final Composite parent, final TableViewer viewer){
        String[] titles = {"Name", "Date Modified", "Size"};
        int[] width = {200, 200, 200};

        //first column is for the name of the file
        TableViewerColumn col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], width[0], 0);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element){
                return ((File) element).getName();
            }

            public Image getImage(Object element){
                return getFirsColumnImage((File) element);
            }
        });
        obj = new FirstColumnEditingSupport(tableViewer,this);
        col.setEditingSupport(obj);

        //second column is for the last date modified
        col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[1], width[1], 1);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element){
                return formatLastModifiedDate((File) element);
            }
        });

        //third column is for size
        col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[2], width[2], 2);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element){
                return formatLength((File) element);
            }
        });
    }

    private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String title, int width, final int columnNumber){
        final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
        column.setText(title);
        column.setWidth(width);
        column.setResizable(true);
        column.setMoveable(false);
        column.addSelectionListener(getSelectionAdapter(column, columnNumber));
        return viewerColumn;
    }

    private SelectionAdapter getSelectionAdapter(final TableColumn column, final int index){
        SelectionAdapter selectionAdapter = new SelectionAdapter(){
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e){
                tableComparator.setColumn(index);
                int direction = tableComparator.getDirection();
                tableViewer.getTable().setSortDirection(direction);
                tableViewer.getTable().setSortColumn(column);
                tableViewer.refresh();
            }
        };

        return selectionAdapter;
    }

    /*
     * method used to return the last modified date in "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" format
     */
    private String formatLastModifiedDate(File file){
        Date d = new Date(file.lastModified());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        return sdf.format(d);
    }

    /*
     * method used to return the length of the file in KB
     */
    private String formatLength(File file){
        long size = file.length()/1024;
        NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#,###,### KB");

        return f.format(size);
    }

}
```

FirstColumnEditingSupport.java file:

```java
/*
 * The EditingSupport implementation defines how the content can be changed.
 */
public class FirstColumnEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {

    private TableViewer tableViewer;
    private FileTableView view;
    private TextCellEditor textEditor;

    public FirstColumnEditingSupport(TableViewer viewer, FileTableView view) {
        super(viewer);
        this.tableViewer = viewer;
        this.view = view;
        textEditor = new TextCellEditor(tableViewer.getTable());
    }

    @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport#getCellEditor(java.lang.Object)
     * EditingSupport returns in his getCellEditor() method an object of type CellEditor. This object creates the controls to change the data.
     */
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        return textEditor;
    }

    @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport#canEdit(java.lang.Object)
     * The canEdit() method defines, if the cell can be edited.
     */
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        return view.getCellEditable();
    }

    @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport#getValue(java.lang.Object)
     * The getValue() method receives the current object and returns the value which should be displayed.
     */
    protected Object getValue(Object element) {
        return ((File) element).getName();
    }

    @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport#setValue(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
     * The method setValue() in EditingSupport receives the changed value based on the user input. In this method you assign the value to your data object.
     */
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
        //value is the user input
        File oldFile = (File) element;

        //String path = oldFile.getAbsolutePath().substring(oldFile.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.pathSeparatorChar));
        //System.out.println(oldFile.getParent());
        oldFile.renameTo(new File(oldFile.getParent() + "\\" + (String) value));
        tableViewer.refresh();
    }

    public TextCellEditor getTextCellEditor(){
        return textEditor;
    }

}
```

My RenameAction file:

```java
public class RenameAction extends Action implements ISelectionListener, ActionFactory.IWorkbenchAction {

    private final IWorkbenchWindow window;
    private IStructuredSelection itemSelected;

    public final static String ID = PlatformUI.PLUGIN_ID + ".RenameAction";

    public RenameAction(IWorkbenchWindow window){
        this.window = window;
        setId(ID);
        setText("&Rename");
        setToolTipText("Rename the file or directory selected");
        window.getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
        if(selection.isEmpty() || !(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)){
            return;         
        }else {
            itemSelected = (IStructuredSelection)selection;
        }
    }

    public void dispose(){
        window.getSelectionService().removeSelectionListener(this);
    }

    public void run(){
        Object firstElement = itemSelected.getFirstElement();

        File item = (File) firstElement;    

        if(item != null){
            FileTableView myTreeView= (FileTableView) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(FileTableView.ID);
            myTreeView.setCellEditable(true);
        }

    }

}
```

My idea was:

- by default: the cell editor of the first column is disabled
- when the rename action is triggered (press the menu button), the cell editor of the column is enabled (`myTreeView.setCellEditable(true)`)
- the table line selected is in editing mode and you can change the name of the file. This part is not working quite well, because after you press the rename menu button, you can't see that the editing mode is enabled. After you click on the table line, the editing mode is activated. Also, the editing mode is enabled for all the table lines and I wanted to be enabled only for the selected one. For this problem I haven't got a solution.
- after you finish typing the new name of the file, and change the selection (click on a different table line), the editing mode is disabled:

  ```java
  tableViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener(){
          public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event){
              setCellEditable(false);
          }
      });
  ```

I hope my solution can help you.